# Issue Integrating Authorize.NET with Magento 2

Tags: magento, checkout, authorize.net, magento-2.0

I have integrated my `Authorize.NET` sandbox account with my `Magento 2.2` website.
I'm getting the following error :

> Sorry, but something went wrong. Please contact the seller.

I have attached screenshots related to the `Magento` configuration and also sent request data and corresponding received response.

One more thing to mention : I have enabled test mode in my sandbox account in `Authorize.NET`. 
Please help if anyone have any idea about this.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/PsnVDce.png         
https://i.imgur.com/hVPWOYH.jpg             
https://i.imgur.com/kBj7iU1.jpg              
https://i.imgur.com/84KyBGY.png

Comment: Enable logs and see if a more detailed message appears in system.log, debug.log, or exception.log.

Comment: In exception.log file, i get this error message "CRITICAL: Please enter a transaction ID to authorize this payment"

Comment: Looks like some other people had the same problem. Try this maybe?
 https://community.magento.com/t5/Admin-Configuration-Questions/Authorize-net-not-working/td-p/23938